# Pin chart from SSRS to Power BI not working

Tags: powerbi, ssrs-2017

I’m trying to pin an chart from SSRS to Power BI. When I pin a chart in SSRS to a Power BI Dashboard I get ‘Pin Successful’. When I look add it in my Power BI Dashboard I get ‘We can’t load the content of this tile. Please delete it and try repinning’. When I repin it the result is the same. But when I click on the tile it opens the report in SSRS.

I've followed the steps from here https://radacad.com/sql-server-reporting-services-integration-with-power-bi

Any Idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this is the response from Microsoft:

We were able to reproduce the issue inhouse and we deem it as a bug.

The fix is applied and it is scheduled to release in the 2nd week of July. Unfortunately , we have to wait till then as there is no workaround at this moment.